# How to create a non-data gc.log file?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I see that my gc.log files are data files while other log files are ASCII text.

Due to that I cannot grep through the non-gc.log files.

```
$ pwd
/app/tomcat7/logs


$ du -hsmc *log* | sort -n

50  access_log2016-11-21.log
74  access_log2016-11-25.log
79  access_log2016-11-24.log
300 gc.log-20161118
418 gc.log-20161119
542 gc.log-20161120



$ file access_log2016-11-24.log gc.log-20161118
access_log2016-11-24.log: ASCII text
gc.log-20161118:          data



$ time grep a access_log2016-11-24.log  | wc -l
426520

real    0m0.888s
user    0m0.740s
sys 0m0.150s



$ time grep a gc.log-20161118
Binary file gc.log-20161118 matches

real    0m9.574s
user    0m9.278s
sys 0m0.274s
```

You can see that it is taking much longer to grep in the gc.log file and it does not return a useful result.

Argument to print GC into gc.log file is `-Xloggc:/app/tomcat7/logs/gc.log`

How do I ensure that the gc.log file is created as an ASCII text file rather than a data file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that grep is interpreting the GC log as a binary data file, where it is actually text. If you use the -a or --text parameter on grep it will treat it as text.

grep -a a gc.log-20161118

Comment: This helped but it still takes a long time. About 10 seconds. While the other file (which is about one fourth the size) takes less than a second.

Comment: I think -a usage is probably incorrect. Any pointers on how to make the log file non-data would be great because the above grep sometimes runs into more than 30 seconds.